# for statement will not run in batch script

Tags: for-loop, batch-file

I'm kinda a bit of a noob to this stuff.  I'm trying to make a batch script to convert Backup Exec 10 xml log files to text.

I got some great answers from here when searching, cooked up a script and have tried to run it.  It bombs at the first "for" statement and I'm not sure why.

I can run every step of this script manually and it works great.  But if I double click on the batch file and run it, after the second pause it bombs.

Anyone see anything out of place here?  I'm at my wits end.  I think the "for" statement might need tweaking.  I've been messing around but haven't found the right combo for it to run successfully in the script.

```
@echo off
echo Starting Backup To Text SCript...
pause
cd c:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec\Data
echo Get the latest BEX_TAPEBACKUP File...
pause
FOR /F "usebackq" %f in (`dir /Od /B`) do set "FILE=%f"
echo %FILE% will be converted to text
pause
cd c:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec
REM This command will take the current Backup Exec XML log file and convert it to text.
pause
bemcmd -o31 -l"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Backup Logs\backuplog.txt" s0 -       f"C:\Program Files\Symantec\Backup Exec\Data\%FILE%"
pause
echo Done
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the right syntax for your for loop:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /od /B') do set "FILE=%%~f"
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for the information and quick response!  Funny I was reading about that here.  http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html  I've learned a lot from these forums!

Answer (score 1):

You need to double your %'s in the For.

```
  FOR /F "usebackq" %%f in (`dir /Od /B`) do set "FILE=%%f"
```

Comment: This only works for short file names without spaces :)